# Wait for CSS animation to complete before scrolling in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I want to achieve an effect similar to the one seen on the homepage of [this](https://noformat.com/) website, in which the content of the current section scales down to reveal a coloured border before scrolling. I'm not sure what code this site uses for it's fullpage scrolling, but I want to use fullpage.js to achieve this.

Essentially, I want to be able to wait for a CSS animation to finish before the section scrolls to the next one.

My idea was to use the fullpage.js `onLeave` function, returning false to cancel the scroll event and then using `fullpage_api.moveSectionUp()` to move to the next section after a `setTimeout` (the CSS animation timing is always the same so I can just hardcode it into the `timeout`.

**The Problem**

I found the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993360/9267033) SO answer to do almost exactly what I want, but the only problem is that the section only scrolls to the next section once you stop scrolling, meaning that if you don't stop scrolling for a few seconds, the scroll will be delayed further than the animation time.

Here is the code I'm using from [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993360/9267033):

```
let done = false;
let animationTimeout;
let transitionTimeout;
let delay = 300;
let transitionTime = 300;

...

    onLeave: function (origin, destination, direction) {

        if (done) return ;

        // cancel any previous timeout as onLeave fires quite a bit.
        clearTimeout(animationTimeout);
        clearTimeout(transitionTimeout);

        // SCALING ANIMATION HERE (done by adding a class to the section)

        animationTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{

            // deal with scroll
            done = true;

            if (direction === 'down') {

                fullpage_api.moveSectionDown();

            } else {

                fullpage_api.moveSectionUp();

            }

            transitionTimeout = setTimeout(()=>done = false, transitionTime);

        }, delay);

        return done;

    },
```

You can also see in [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9w1tb85p/46/) that fullpage.js won't scroll to the next section until you stop scrolling...

**So...**

How can I wait for a CSS animation to finish before fullpage.js scrolls to the next section?

Comment: See my answer in this same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182162/1081396

Comment: @Alvaro Your accepted answer to that question only works for the first scroll down for me. A delay is added to the first one but scrolling down to the 3rd screen has no delay...

Comment: Yeah. That'st just a example of how to implement it. See the code and apply it to as many sections as you want with the delays you need for each of them.